# Remove Visual Composer Tab from Dashboard Menu

Tags: dashboard

I have installed Visual Composer for a client and am now trying to remove the tab from the Dashboard menu. How can I do this?

[image: Remove Visual Composer tab from Dashboard menu]

```
function remove_menus(){

    remove_menu_page( ‘js_composer.php’ );      

}

add_action( ‘admin_menu’, ‘remove_menus’ );
```

The code used above isn't working for me. It seems the path "js_composer.php" is not correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not easy to find it out, but it is pretty easy if you know how.

Add this following code to your themes `functions.php`.

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page('vc-welcome'); //vc
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

(Previously been `admin_menu`, now is `admin_init`)

This is how to find out for the next time:

If you want to hide a link from any plugin in the admin backend, simply use everything behind the `?page=` in this example case it's `vc-welcome`

No need for an additional plugin to remove/hide the link.

Comment: Very useful information well explained!

Comment: Doesn't work still there. @user2511140 is the correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelRogers it's exactly the same code. This answer is more basic. If the menu name changed from `vc-general` to `vc-welcome` then the answer is still in it as it says `simply use everything behind the ?page= in this case it's vc-general`

Comment: @MichaelRogers both answers have identical code, and both answers and the question are all off topic, 3rd party plugin dev support is not in this stacks scope

Comment: Delete the question then? I didn't make it.

Comment: That's not how stackexchange works @MichaelRogers. It is closed but feel free to edit the question so it is more general.

Comment: @TomJNowell very nitpicking. This is applicable on every plugin, so it is not plugin specific.

Comment: @marvinpoo as a moderator I follow the rules and scope, if you disagree with the rules and scope or feel that this is an edge case then you should open a question on the meta stack. Complaining in comments does not change the result, we have a process

Comment: @TomJNowell then you should be the one to review the edit, so the edit won't be rejected for the wrong reason.

Comment: Personally I don't believe the edit substantially changes it, and may make it worse by explicitly referencing a specific plugin. It would then mean that your answer would technically no longer be the correct answer as your answer specifically refers to Visual Composer. It's a good question with a good answer, it just got asked on the wrong site. As I closed the question I've left the edit for someone else to check, but even if it is approved that's not a guarantee that the question would become on topic

Comment: But as I mentioned earlier, _post on the meta stack_, comments are not for discussing the site, they're for clarifying a question or answer. I look forward to your post

Answer (score 4):

I use version 4.12.1 and this code works for me. Hide from user menu but not for admin menu.

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page('vc-welcome'); //vc
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers did not work for me. I realized that I had to change the hook to **admin_init**.

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page('vc-welcome');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've updated my answer, 'cause it's the accepted one so people can find it fast. Kudos for you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing the [Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) plugin which gave me the ability to manually remove the Visual Composer dashboard tab. Good plugin!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked out for me on the latest Wordpress

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page('vc-welcome');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```